# How to make column numbers of pandas dataframe to start from 1 instead of 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe containing 4000 rows and 60630 columns.
ml_file_df.
The column numbers start from 0 and goes on till 60629

```
   0      1       2         3
0 100    -5       jaya     27
1 80     1.5      shree    30
2 75     3.2      raju     31
```

I want my header to start from 1.

```
   1      2       3         4
0 100    -5       jaya     27
1 80     1.5      shree    30
2 75     3.2      raju     31
```

I tried using

```
ml_file_df.rename(columns = [i for i in range(1,60630)])
```

I am getting this error

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

How to solve this

Comment: Use `df.columns = range(1, len(df.columns)+1)` or `np.arange(1, df.shape[1]+1)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assign new values:

```
df.columns = pd.RangeIndex(1, len(df.columns)+1)
```

Or simply add `1`:

```
df.columns += 1
```

Comment: `df.columns += 1` :D

Comment: `df.columns += 1` - Damn, I can't believe it was so simple. Thanks a lot!